need help finding the solution to startup error NoClassDefFoundError for javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
upgraded to jdk17 and springboot 3.2.4
need help finding the solution to startup error, below?
i.e.,
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig': Invocation of init method failed
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig': Invocation of init method failed
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>           
                    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>common-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>        
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.30.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.14</version>
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>32.1.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.4.0</version> 
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20240303</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
          
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>        
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
                                
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>pojo-tester</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


It would help if you shared your POM. From what versions are you updating from? Is com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs defined in the POM?

provided dependencies in description. thx :-)

Analize your maven dependencies and to find what has a dependency on javax/ws. You will have to update this dependency to a version the supports jakarta/ws. You can use the maven-dependency-plugin maven plugin to assist in this effort.

mvn dependency:tree shows no sign of:   javax.ws  at all
